# How to Prevent react from converting named colors to hex codes in css?

Tags: css, reactjs, compilation, styling

I am currently having an issue trying to render a white apple pay button in a react app. Here is the html

```html
<div style={{width: "100%", height: "auto", backgroundColor: 'white'}} className="apple-pay-button-with-text apple-pay-button-white-with-text">
     <span class="text">Buy with</span>
     <span class="logo"></span>
</div>
```

And then the css

```css
    .apple-pay-button-with-text {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        -webkit-appearance: -apple-pay-button;
        -apple-pay-button-type: buy;
        -apple-pay-button-style:  white;
    }
    .apple-pay-button-with-text > * {
        display: none;
    }
    .apple-pay-button-black-with-text {
        -apple-pay-button-style: black;
    }
    .apple-pay-button-white-with-line-with-text {
        -apple-pay-button-style: white-outline;
    }
    .apple-pay-button-white-with-text {
        -apple-pay-button-style:  white;
    }
```

The issue I am running into is that once this is rendered in browser, white gets converted into it's hex value, which -apple-pay-button-style does not recognize so it renders a black apple pay button. I can use white-outline and that obviously doesn't get converted, but it is not the desired style. Is there anyway to prevent the name white from being converted into it's hex value?

Comment: Not sure I follow. `white` from your inline CSS gets converted to hex? `style={{width: "100%", height: "auto", backgroundColor: 'white'}}`

Comment: No, the style in the css sheet "-apple-pay-button-style: white" gets converted to "apple-pay-button-style: #fff"

Comment: make a variable `white` and give the results whatever you want (ex: rgb)

Comment: just tried implementing this and it still get's converted to the hexcode

Comment: @BKelly i'm facing a similar. did you manage to solve it? If so how?

Comment: @BKelly can you help me solve the same issue?